# Let's get down to the really exciting parts

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Because I'm preparing for my 50th puzzle tomorrow (I got something special planned), I created a simple riddle for today.

> Following what's happened before, this is what you were waiting for.
> I guarantee you I won't bore, I'll leave you breathless, wanting more.
>
> Very exciting, I'll amaze and astound,
> Every writing, will keep me laying around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Previous answer:

> Plot twist

Are you

> A climax?

The hidden clue, as well as some help from Joe leads me to

> [This site](http://changingminds.org/disciplines/storytelling/plots/five_stage/five_stage.htm)  detailing the FIVE (classic Acrostic Joe) stage story structure

Following what's happened before, this is what you were waiting for.

> The peak of the story

I guarantee you I won't bore, I'll leave you breathless, wanting more. Very exciting, I'll amaze and astound,

> This is the most exciting part of the story

Every writing, will keep me laying around.

> Climax or climaxes are in every piece of writing worth its salt. A very important part.

Comment: It's not this, but you're so close, it's agonizing!

Comment: What about this, @Joe-You-Know?

Comment: That's it! Good job

Comment: Out of curiosity, was that the same five-step process?

Comment: Yes, it is the same five-step process

Answer (score 3):

**First two guesses (both incorrect)**

> Newspaper, and story

Are you (I don't think you are, but worth a shot anyway)

> Creative writing?

Following what's happened before, this is what you were waiting for.

> When you write (especially sequels), your plotline tends to follow previously told stories (ie. the Odyssey follows the Iliad). You might be waiting for the story especially if the previous part ended on a cliff hanger, or you might be waiting for a spark of creativity/inspiration.

I guarantee you I won't bore, I'll leave you breathless, wanting more.

> Good creative writing yields really interesting stories and the twists and turns and cliff hangers can leave people on the edge of their seats.

Very exciting, I'll amaze and astound,

> This seems to be a rehash of the previous line.

Every writing, will keep me laying around.

> Every time you sit down to write and use your imagination, you're bringing your creative writing skills into the physical world.

As for some additional hints:

> "Exciting parts" could refer to writing interesting parts of a story which contain all of the action. Certain parts of the creative writing process are also more interesting than others, I'd imagine

and

> The first letters of each line spell FIVE....creative writing is a five-step process from your hint below?

Comment: Not a bad guess, but this isn't it. It's more of a concept or idea than it is a physical thing.

Comment: Your second guess is closer, but not quite it either.

Comment: Your hints on Zani Xu's post and QuantumTwinkie's posts seem to lead towards something like this...?

Comment: It's part of this answer, but it's a little more specific than that.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> The number 5?

Following what's happened before, this is what you were waiting for.
I guarantee you I won't bore, I'll leave you breathless, wanting more.

> Maybe in five more days you will post, or five hours.

Very exciting, I'll amaze and astound,
Every writing, will keep me laying around.

> I am not sure.

Also,

> The first letter of each line spells five and it is a concept not an object.

But,

> I am not sure and I am thinking this because I just answered a puzzle with 4 as the answer :D

Comment: No, this answer is on the completely wrong path. So far, the closest answer has been El-Guest's. You could say the actual answer is a part of his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Magic?

Following what's happened before, this is what you were waiting for.

> Maybe you are at a magic show?

I guarantee you I won't bore, I'll leave you breathless, wanting more.

> Magic is never boring, and you will always want more.

Very exciting, I'll amaze and astound,

> Magic is very exciting, and it amazes people.

Every writing, will keep me laying around.

> Maybe there are a lot of magic tricks in books?

As for some additional hints:

> The first letter of each line spell five. Maybe five is a good number for magicians?

As for the title,

> Sometimes you may just want to skip to the exciting part

Comment: Another really interesting guess. This isn't the answer. It's more exciting than this.

Comment: More exciting than a puzzle? :O

Comment: Yes, more exciting than that.

Comment: @ZaniXu you and I both are having trouble with those additional hints! It seems so general, but I know it must fit something...

Comment: What does five mean? (Not like the definition, but ya know...)

Comment: It's not this last guess either. Five is referring to rot13(gur snpg gung gur nafjre vf cneg bs n svir-fgrc cebprff)

Comment: Does it have to do with the site itself?

Comment: @ZaniXu, no, it has nothing to do with PSE